# Cannot use type chan []string) as type []chan string?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

```
package main

import "fmt"

func x(foo []string, cz chan string) {
    for i := range foo {
        cz <- foo[i]
    }
}

func y(foo []string, cz chan string) {
    for i := range foo {
        cz <- foo[i]
    }
}

type cz struct {
    cSlice []chan string
}

func main() {

    var quality []string = make([]string, 2)
    quality[0] = "hello"
    quality[1] = "world"
    //name := []string{"mother", "earth"}

    var channel cz

    for i := range channel.cSlice {
        go x(quality, channel.cSlice[i])
        go y(quality, channel.cSlice[i])
        x, y := <-channel.cSlice[i], <-channel.cSlice[i]
        fmt.Println(x, y)
    }
}
```

Nothing gets received now hmm...

Update ^

... need more text.

... and then a little more. Ok how much more?

I really can't believe this. fdsaf asf asfasdfdasfadfd

Comment: Check your function arguments, you ask for a []chan string, which is a slice of channels, not a chan []string.

Comment: Yes I messed up lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cannot use channel.cSlice (type chan []string) as type []chan string in argument to x
cannot use channel.cSlice (type chan []string) as type []chan string in argument to y
```

---

Read the error messages.

`type chan []string`

`type []chan string`

They are different.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/CKhj8DUGTle

Comment: Thanks... but now: invalid operation: <-channel.cSlice (receive from non-chan type []chan string) .. you can't send a slice of chan?

Comment: @user10032371 <- channel.cSlice is not sending anything, it is receiving. I believe the error is occuring because channel.cSlice is a slice of chan's, while, of course, you can only receive from one channel, not a slice of them.

Comment: You appear to be right. I updated the code and it works minus 'quality' not being sent to func x, y.